# How to access gettext translations from lua scripts?

Tags: lua, translation, gettext

In my native C++ application I already have *gettext-based* translations. Some parts of applications are *scriptable* with **Lua** so that I only need to modify the script file without recompiling my app in order to change some parts of app's functionality. In my **Lua** scripts I need the script output to appear in currently selected language.

In order to avoid *translation hell* (separate translations for main application, scripts and installer) I would like to use the same gettext translation file in **Lua** script which I use in my main application. Is it possible and how to achieve this ?

Comment: There exist gettext bindings for Lua.  Just google it.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I saw something on a github but nothing on an official Lua web page so I'm not sure which bindings are really stable and usable ...

Comment: Could you not simple expose the function which does the translation as one usable by lua within your application.